# React Native - Debug with chrome missing

Tags: react-native, react-native-debugger

I cant find "Debug with chrome" options in React Native Debug Menu. I run my application thru IOS.

In my `Podfile` I disable `hermes`

```
:hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
```

[image]

I want to use Debug with chrome in order to connect my app to React Native Debugger

Answer (score 0):

You have to set herms_enabled=false like this in podfile

```
:hermes_enabled => false
```

This will help you to **debug with chrome**.